# Setting GStreamer Element Capabilities and Properties with C

Tags: pipeline, gstreamer

I'm trying to convert a gst_parse_launch(..) pipeline to one created using gst_element_factory_make (..) & gst_bin_add_many (..).

I'm simply trying to understand how to set the capabilities and properties within the gst_element_factory_make() type coding.

For an example I have

```
pipeline = gst_parse_launch(v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=100 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink, NULL);
```

The replacement code is starting with:

```
source = gst_element_factory_make ( "v412src", "source"); 
    
gst_bin_add_many( GST_BIN (pipeline), source, ..... , NULL);
```

Looking at just **v4l2src**, how would I set the following in the new code?

1. Properties: device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=100
2. Capabilities: video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1
   Are their additional functions, or are there parms added to the "make" & "many
   functions?

Thanks for your Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an example for setting capabilities. The basis of this is from the Gstreamer [filter](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/pads.html?gi-language=c#creating-capabilities-for-filtering) documentation. My version:

Place this function above main.

```
static gboolean
link_elements_with_filter(GstElement *element1, GstElement *element2) 
{
    gboolean link_ok;
    GstCaps *caps;
    gchar *name1, *name2;

    caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
              "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "YUY2",
              "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
              "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,
              "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
              NULL);
    
    link_ok = gst_element_link_filtered (element1, element2, caps);
    gst_caps_unref(caps);

    if(!link_ok) {
      g_object_get (G_OBJECT (element1), "name", &name1, NULL);
      g_object_get (G_OBJECT (element2), "name", &name2, NULL);
      g_print ("Failed to link %s element and %s element!\n", name1,name2);
    }

    return link_ok;
}
```

Place in main:

```
// Make elements
source    = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src","source");
convert   = gst_element_factory_make("nvvidconv","convert");
transform = gst_element_factory_make("nvegltransform","transform");
sink      = gst_element_factory_make("nveglglessink","sink");
pipeline  = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

// Add elements to pipeline
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),source, convert, transform, sink, NULL);

// Link all elements except source and convert.
gst_element_link_many(convert,transform,sink, NULL);   }

// Link source & convert + Set specific capabilities 
if (!link_elements_with_filter(source, convert)) {
     // more code  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found example of syntax for Properties in a nvstreammux element.

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (streammux), "width", MUXER_OUTPUT_WIDTH, "height", MUXER_OUTPUT_HEIGHT, "batched-push-timeout", MUXER_BATCH_TIMEOUT_USEC,NULL);
```

NULL caps off entry of pairs.

In my original example, some are defined as Capabilities, like video/x-raw.
I didn't find an example for Capabilities anywhere. These seem to have multiple layers. video/x-raw has format, width, and height. How is the syntax coded?